# Getting value from secondary dropdown in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing two dropdowns in angularjs. First dropdown lists all the countries. And second states dropdown will displayed only for US and Canada.

The states dropdown is listing the states perfectly but I am not getting the value of states dropdown in the scope.

Code:

```
<select ng-if="ProfSettingForm.CountryId.$modelValue == 6" ng-model="StateProv" class="form-control option" ng-init="States = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($allUSStates); ?>"/>
                <option value="">Choose Your State</option>
                <option ng-repeat="state in States" ng-selected="{{state.StateId == StateId}}"
                        value="{{ state.StateId }}">{{state.StateName}}
                </option>
            </select>

            <select ng-if="ProfSettingForm.CountryId.$modelValue == 7" ng-model="StateProv" class="form-control option" ng-init="States = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($allCanProvinces); ?>"/>
            <option value="">Choose Your Province</option>
            <option ng-repeat="state in States" ng-selected="{{state.StateId == StateId}}"
                    value="{{ state.StateId }}">{{state.StateName}}
            </option>
            </select>

<h3>{{"Value="+ProfSettingForm.StateProv.$modelValue}}</h3>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
app.controller("profileSettingCTRL", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

getAllCountries($scope, $http);

$scope.profileSettingSubmit = function (isValid) {

    $scope.successMessage = "";
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.myThumb = $window.imagepath;

    var data = $.param({
        FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
        LastName: $scope.LastName,
        Email: $scope.Email,
        CountryId: $scope.CountryId,
        StateProv: $scope.StateProv,
        DOB: $scope.DOB,
        PictureURL: $scope.myThumb
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share me the more detail or set-up code plnker?

Comment: Which details you want to know?

Comment: Please check, I have added the angularjs code part.

Answer (score 0):

take a scope variable $scope.selectvalue.value in controller and apply it to ng-model like 

you will get selected value in $scope.selectvalue.value

Comment: take a scope variable as in object form it can bind data.